# From every starting node, to every end node, calculate shortest distance. Node to node distance is 1

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path, graph-traversal

I have to calculate the shortest distance, from n staring nodes to n end nodes. I don't care about the actual path. The number of nodes are much larger than n. Every node is connected to exactly 9 nodes. Distance from node to node is 1.
My best idea for it is to do a [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) for a starting node, which if i understand it correctly, would give me n end node distance in linear time, and i would do it for every starting node.

Is there a faster approach to this?

Edit:
The full problem is that i have a 2d race track, a finish line, and a car which have to do a number of laps, and the car can only have 121 different speed vectors, so vx=[-5,5], vy=[-5,5] and can only change its speed vector +-1 every tick. Also the car shouldn't hit the walls. i want to calculate the exact shortest time(tick) it can do these laps. My idea was to make nodes from speed-position pairs and calculate the shortest path from every speed at every finish line point to every speed-position pair at the same finish line. And then use this data to do a separate path finding for the given number of laps knowing the car's starting position.

Comment: "Is there a faster approach" - yes, you chose the naiive solution. You have a simple graph with a simple n-to-n query. Standard shortest path computation. You can for example use a basic Set-Dijkstra algorithm. Or enhance it with an A-star that uses a landmarks heuristic. If you need something to lookup or just want to have the code, you can for example use this simple project I made [ZabuzaW/Maglev](https://github.com/ZabuzaW/Maglev/wiki).

Comment: Nevermind, your edges all have a weight of exactly 1. A BFS or DFS will do the trick. Depending on the graph structure a goal-direction heuristic would greatly improve the algorithm though. From your broad description, sounds like A-star with as-the-crows-fly would do the trick. Landmarks also work well. Note that a Dijkstra with all edges the same weight is basically just BFS.

Comment: Voting to close as the question is missing necessary details. For example, we can not find a good heuristic without knowing the exact structure of the graph.

Comment: I edited my question with more detail. I looked into the A-star algorithm, and it indeed seems a faster algorithm than my naive way, but i couldn't figure out how i can do n to n calculation with it without redoing it every time with every starting point. In your project the "the closest sources to all reachable nodes" would do something like this?

Comment: Yes. You have a set-dijkstra (you just start by adding all those nodes as starting nodes to the queue). And then you abort as soon as you settled all required destination nodes. So basic Dijkstra + adding all starting nodes to the initial queue + stopping after settling all destinations, not just one. Then add the a heuristic to get a-star (a-star is dijkstra with heuristic). I cant tell you which heuristic is best without knowing details about the graph structure. But landmarks is always very good (ALT). As-the-crow-flies is trivial but might work well, depending on structure.

Answer (score -1):

yeah, use Djikstra's shortest path algorithm:

1) Create a set sptSet (shortest path tree set) that keeps track of vertices included in shortest path tree, i.e., whose minimum distance from source is calculated and finalized. Initially, this set is empty.

2) Assign a distance value to all vertices in the input graph. Initialize all distance values as INFINITE. Assign distance value as 0 for the source vertex so that it is picked first.

3) While sptSet doesn’t include all vertices

….a) Pick a vertex u which is not there in sptSet and has minimum distance value.

….b) Include u to sptSet.

….c) Update distance value of all adjacent vertices of u. To update the distance values, iterate through all adjacent vertices. For every adjacent vertex v, if sum of distance value of u (from source) and weight of edge u-v, is less than the distance value of v, then update the distance value of v.

Comment: A simple Dijkstra does **not** improve over BFS if all edge weights are equal (as OP said), because it basically is a dumb BFS then. What you need to actually improve the algorithm here is a goal direction heuristic like as-the-crows-fly or ALT (landmarks). Downvoted for not useful, see [answer], thanks.